# can't placing icon in newest version from react-sidebar-pro

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-sidebar

i'm having a trouble with placing icon in  component from react-sidebar-pro.

[image]

The documentation says, we can placing icon in  Component.

[image]

But when i'm trying to give props like this.

```
   <SubMenu label="Admisi" icon={faHome}>
       <Menuitem routerLink={<Link to="/admisi/rawat-darurat-igd" className='txt-blue-grey-800'/>} style={{marginRight: 5}}>Rawat Darurat (IGD)</Menuitem>
       <Menuitem routerLink={<Link to="/admisi/rawat-inap" className='txt-blue-grey-800'/>} style={{marginRight: 5}}>Rawat Inap</Menuitem>
   </SubMenu>
```

i'm getting the error.

[image]

i don't know how to solved this problem, i've been trying for looking another example, but that's not enough for solving my problem. Any help will be apreciated. Thankyou

Comment: What is `faHome`?

Comment: My guess (based solely on what's visible in your question) is that `faHome` has an `icon` property, and that's what you should be passing instead. `icon={faHome.icon}`.

Comment: How might we change the icon when a submenu is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass `<faHome />` instead of `faHome` to icon prop as follow :

```
<SubMenu label="Admisi" icon={<faHome />}>
...
```